# How to sort a list with dictionaries into ascending order

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, sorting

I used *reduceRegion* to get statistics of certain provinces in Germany. I get a list with dictionaries (province ID, histogram and median) and would like to sort the list by the median values. I have issues to get the list sorted.  This is what I have so far:

```
var geometry = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[2.165739166604279, 55.7242449869763],
          [2.165739166604279, 45.702626323936244],
          [19.56808291660428, 45.702626323936244],
          [19.56808291660428, 55.7242449869763]]], null, false),
    DEU = ee.FeatureCollection("users/gaertnerp/DEU_gadm1");

var NO2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S5P/NRTI/L3_NO2')
.filterBounds(geometry).select('NO2_column_number_density')
.map(function(img) {return img.multiply(1e6).copyProperties(img,['system:time_start']); }) 
.filterDate('2020-01-01', '2020-02-15').median().rename('NO2');

var empty = ee.Image().byte();

var outline = empty.paint({
  featureCollection: DEU,
  color: 'ID1'
});

var reducers = ee.Reducer.histogram().combine({
  reducer2: ee.Reducer.median().unweighted(),
  sharedInputs: true
});

var hist = NO2.addBands(outline).reduceRegion({
  reducer: reducers.repeat(1).group({
    groupField: 1, 
    groupName: 'NAME_1'
  }),
  geometry: geometry,
  scale: 5000,
  maxPixels: 1e15
})

var groups = ee.List(hist.get('groups'))
groups = groups.slice(0,5)
print('groups',groups)
```

Here is the list I would like to sort by the median value.

[image]

Comment: Here is the link to the script https://code.earthengine.google.com/bfcc0ec4418f3c1b78ab1a8b5f0faff2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is my attemp. First make a list of medians. Then use that list as keys to sort. It works, although im not sure it is the best way...

```
var keys = groups.map(function(x){
  return ee.Feature(null, x).get('median')}).map(function(n){
    return ee.List(n).get(0)
  })

var sortedGroups = groups.sort(keys)
print(sortedGroups)
```

abrazo

Comment: Hola Javier, thanks for your solution, it does exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

I'll tell you how I would do it in theory, but be warned that it doesn't work without extra effort in your case. But it's an easy fix nevertheless.

I would convert the list of dictionaries into a FeatureCollection which then can be sorted. Like this:

```
var no2features = ee.FeatureCollection(groups.map(function(dict){
  return ee.Feature(null, dict)
}))

var sorted = no2features.sort('median'))
print(sorted)
```

This doesn't work for you, because you've put `.repeat(1)` in line 23. However `.repeat(1)` does nothing for you, other than wrapping your median result into a list which can't be sorted. So if you delete this function call, the code will also work for you.